# The application can't find the module dist

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJs Application and I try to start it in terminal using npm run start:prod. I receive the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../dist'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern-starter@2.0.0 start:prod: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-starter@2.0.0 start:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And there is indeed no dist folder or file. What is it usually used for?
Do you know how it can be solved?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: I guess you use React.Js

Comment: I'm using Node.js

Comment: please try to share you structure and serer file code.